# Mocktail: what are you actually testing?

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter Mocktail and I was wondering how it works, because to me it looks like I am just injecting some values and these are verified without actually ensuring the functionality works as desired.

Here is an example:

```
  test('Dices are used', () {

      when(() => dices.diceOne.use()).thenReturn(true);
      when(() => dices.areUsed()).thenReturn(false);
      expect(dices.areUsed(), false);

      when(() => dices.diceTwo.use()).thenReturn(true);
      when(() => dices.areUsed()).thenReturn(true);
      expect(dices.areUsed(), isTrue);


    });

//Dice
 void use() {
    if (isDoubleDice) {
      isDoubleDice = false;
    } else {
      used = true;
    }
  }

//Dices
  bool areUsed() {
    return diceOne.used && diceTwo.used;
  }
```

My scenario here is the following:

- when using the first dice, ensure areUsed is false
- after using the second dice as well, ensure areUsed is True

To me it looks like all I am doing here in reality is just "ok i assign this with true in this line from the mocker, on the next line I'll ensure it is actually true.

Could someone explain what exactly this Mocktail tries to achieve when doing stuff like this?

Even in the [mocktail's documentation example](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail/example) There is this part:

```
class Cat {
  String sound() => 'meow!';
  bool likes(String food, {bool isHungry = false}) => false;
  void eat<T extends Food>(T food) {}
  final int lives = 9;
}

// A Mock Cat class
class MockCat extends Mock implements Cat {}



 test('example', () {
      // Stub a method before interacting with the mock.
      when(() => cat.sound()).thenReturn('purr');

      // Interact with the mock.
      expect(cat.sound(), 'purr');
```

What does it test here? It just assigns a random string to the sound, then expects that when calling cat.sound, the result is the string that was assigned 1 line before. What is exactly tested here and how is this approach usefull?

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of how to use mocktail.

In my example, I'm using `MockCat` to test the `CatOwner` class.
This allows me to quickly change the outcome of the functions in the `Cat` class, without needing to initiate a new `Cat` and a new `CatOwner` instance.

The doc in mocktail only shows you how the lib is working. Not really on how to use it.

```dart
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';

class Cat {
  final List<String> preferredFoods;
  
  Cat(this.preferredFoods);

  bool likes(String food) => preferredFoods.contains(food);
}

class CatOwner {
  final Cat cat;
  const CatOwner(this.cat);

  bool get catLikesFish => cat.likes('fish');
}

// A Mock Cat class
class MockCat extends Mock implements Cat {}

void main() {
  final MockCat cat = MockCat();
  final CatOwner catOwner = CatOwner(cat);

  test('test CatOwner', () {
    when(() => cat.likes('fish')).thenReturn(true);
    expect(catOwner.catLikesFish, true);

    when(() => cat.likes('fish')).thenReturn(false);
    expect(catOwner.catLikesFish, false);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of mocking is to test behavior of *other* objects that interact with mocked objects.  There is no point to testing the mocked objects themselves.  For example, if you have two classes `A` and `B` and want to verify that calling `A.foo()` triggers a call to `B.bar()`, then you would give `A` a reference to a `MockB` object to use, call `A.foo()`, and then verify that the `MockB.bar()` was called.

You're right that your example and that the example from the Mocktail documentation don't test anything.  The example from the Mocktail documentation is intended only to show you how to create stubs and how to verify interactions with the mocked object.  In practice, a test would never interact with a mock directly.